# xsser fails to find easy XSS vulnerability (Web For Pentester)

Tags: penetration-test, xss, reflected-xss

I tried to evaluate the effectivity of xsser (http://xsser.03c8.net) by letting it run against the "Web For Pentester" XSS tests (https://pentesterlab.com/exercises/web_for_pentester/course) is it implements very easy exploitable XSS vulnerabilities and thus serve as a good baseline.

However, the tool fails to find even the simplest (example 1) XSS vulnerability. If I understood correctly, the tool generates a unique hash per test case and checks if this hash is reflected in the response body.

However, looking at the verbose output and re-submitting one of the tests, the response indeed includes the hashes. So to me it seems like xsser generates a lot of false negatives.

Can somebody reproduce or tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Could you provide a way to reproduce the problem? If I understand correctly, the lab you're linking to is behind a paywall.

Comment: The exercises, especially Web For Pentesters are free: https://pentesterlab.com/exercises/